# Use fork instead of the original repository

Tags: php, json, symfony, github, composer-php

On many occasions I have made forks from some repositories in order to correct the bugs or add new features as a contribution. In this case, when I do the PR the developers behind master repository, sometimes, take days to make the merge and test that all is well and most of the time I need to test on these changes in hot or at the time that I am performing.

Such is the case of `SpBowerBundle` which have made a fork and fix some things. I've done the PR but I can not wait for the developer to perform their tests and do the merge. The only solution is to point the `composer.json` to the fork I've done but do not how.

This is the [forked repository](https://github.com/paquitodev/SpBowerBundle) and this is [the commit](https://github.com/paquitodev/SpBowerBundle/commit/afecc841be9126b5ade4812ec7daa4142f53ab82) I made. As addition here is my `composer.json` content:

```
{
    "name": "NewProject",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "NewProject",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "1.5.*@dev",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.13.*@dev",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.4.*@dev",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.4.*@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "2.7.*@dev",
        "genemu/form-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
        "misd/phone-number-bundle": "~1.0",
        "liip/monitor-bundle": "dev-master",
        "raulfraile/ladybug-bundle": "~1.0",
        "sp/bower-bundle": "0.12.*@dev",
        "h4cc/alice-fixtures-bundle": "dev-bug/30-command-reference"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Liip\\MonitorBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::checkHealth"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Liip\\MonitorBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::checkHealth"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
        },
        "symfony-assets-install": "symlink"
    }
}
```

How do I point my composer to the forked repository? Which is the best way to deal with this?

**Update**

After @Cerad suggestion I made this changes to `composer.json` file but still not updating from fork, what I'm doing wrong?

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/Spea/SpBowerBundle.git"
    }
],
"require": {
    ....
    "sp/bower-bundle": "dev-master",
},
```

Comment: Don't consider this a fully fleshed out answer, but you may consider putting your own package versions up on packagist and then just pointing composer to your own package.  This'll make it easy to manage your composer config, use your most recent changes, and allow the package maintainers to do their thing while you wait.

Comment: Or you could read the composer manual on accessing github repositories directly.

Comment: @Cerad you mean something like [this](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository)?

Comment: @ReynierPM Consider marking this question as unanswered if the answer didn't solve your problem – this will motivate user to find an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Add your repository to the `repositories` and, providing it has the original `composer.json`, it should use that instead.

```
{
    ....
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/paquitodev/SpBowerBundle"
        }
    ],
    ....
}
```